# Tomcat and Struts 2 - Active Directory Authentication in Interceptor

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2, active-directory, ldap

I have LDAP authentication setup in my Tomcat server, and roles defined which works for login. I want to allow everyone on the domain to login, which is all sorted.

I have a struts2 interceptor which checks username against a database in order to permit CRUD operations. I want to also check if a user is in a chosen LDAP group, if so allow invoke the action.

How can I check the LDAP groups of a user from a Struts 2 interceptor?

Perhaps there is a better approach to this problem?

Comment: 0 down vote
 

I've never used Tomcat container security - I always implement security within the webapp itself. However, my first port of call if HttpServletRequest.getUserPrincipal() or HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole()didn't return anything useful would be to use a debugger to have a look at the Struts session map to see if Tomcat has put anything useful in there.